# Xcode - filter an NSFetchRequest and select each object

Tags: xcode, ios6, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to filter a fetchRequest.

I'm at the point where the result is loaded into an NSArray.

However, I need to parse the array to pull out the individual items - right now, they look as if they were one object.

The code I'm using to get to this point is:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = coreDataController.mainThreadContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

[request setEntity:entity];


    // Order the events by name.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // Execute the fetch -- create a mutable copy of the result.
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *categories = [[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    if (categories == nil) {
        NSLog(@"bugger");
    }

    NSObject *value = nil;
    value = [categories valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

This results as follows:

```
 value = (
)

[DetailViewController loadPickerArray]
[AppDelegate loadPickerArray]
 value = (
    "Cat Two",
    "Cat Three",
    "Cat One",
    "Cat Four"
)
```

Also, please note that the first time this ran, there were no results. I get that about 50% of the time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. By "filter", do you mean return items that meet a certain condition? If so, why don't you just attach an `NSPredicate` to your request?

Comment: The category entity has three fields and for this purpose, I only want the name. I get that but it returns as one object (in brackets), not four. I'm dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `categories` is an array, calling `valueForKeyPath:` on it will return an array with the values (for keypath) of each object in the array.

Comment: Thanks Leo, so how do I treat the resulting array to get each value? If you phrase this as an answer, I can mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods you can filter your data.

The preferred way is to use a predicate for your search. This will give you the best performance.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = coreDataController.mainThreadContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

[request setEntity:entity];

// Order the events by name.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[CD] %@", @"Cat"]; //This will return all objects that contain 'cat' in their name property.

[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// Execute the fetch -- create a mutable copy of the result.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *categories = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (categories == nil) {
    NSLog(@"bugger");
}

//Here you have the objects you want in categories.

for(Category *category in categories)
{
    NSLog(@"Category name: %@", category.name);
}
```

If you wish to filter using an array, the following is possible also:

```
NSMutableArray *categories = [[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

[categories filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[CD] %@", @"Cat"]]

//Now, the only objects left in categories will be the ones with "cat" in their name property.
```

I recommend reading the [Predicates Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html), as predicates are very powerful, and it is much more efficient to filter your results in the store.

Comment: Thank you so much Leo. Just couldn't get my head around the last phrase. Thanks for the link to the predicates guide too. I dont need to filter these, but this will come in very handy.

Comment: Cheers. Let me know if you need help with anything else.

Comment: hmm. thanks. This stuff is being pulled in from iCloud. It's working about 50% of the time. So 50%, I get a null array, rerun the app and the array is populated.. Anything come to mind? I do have notifications posted..

Comment: The Predicates Programming Guide above is a broken link... here is an updated link:[Predicates Programming Guide:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html)